# Sign of permutations and cycle lengths

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For any $\tau \in S_n$, the sign of $\tau$ is 1 if $\sum_{c\in\tau}((\text{cycle length of } c) -1)$ is even; the sign of $\tau$ is $-1$ if $\sum_{c\in\tau}((\text{cycle length of } c) -1)$ is odd? ($c$ is any cycle in $\tau$)

Comment: What is your definition of sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definition of sign is based on the observation that every permutation is a product of transpositions. The sign of a permutation is then $(-1)^k$ if the permutation is a product of $k$ transpositions. (The hard part is proving that the sign does not depend on $k$, but only on the parity of $k$, that is, the parity of all different expressions of the same permutation as a product of transpositions is constant.)

With this definition, your result follows immediately from these two simple facts, which are easy to prove:

- Every cycle of length $m$ can be written as a product of $m-1$ transpositions.
- Every permutation is a product of cycles.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!